# How do I repeatedly print this string until it reaches a certain number?

Tags: java, for-loop

This program *should* print the word as many times as the word is long but it doesn't work for some reason. for instance this program should print;

hippo

hippo

hippo

hippo

hippo

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Box {
    private String word;

    public Box() {
        word = null;
    }

    public Box(String s) {
        word = s;
    }

    public void setWord(String s) {
        word = s;
    }

    public String value() {
        int length = word.length();
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            return word;
        }

        return null;
    }



    public String toString() {
        return "" + value();
    }

}

public class BoxRunner {    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Box run = new Box();
        run.setWord("hippo");
        run.value();

        System.out.print(run.toString());
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the box class, `public String value()` is supposed to the word repeat as many times as the word is long.

Comment: Not answering your question, but you don't need to import `java.lang.System.*`. The `lang` library is imported automatically.

Comment: You don't want to return inside the for loop. You probably want to print. Second `toString` runs `value` so your code is doing the same thing twice.

Comment: Was that a java joke? For _instance_?

Answer (score 0):

The return keyword in Java will exit the current method you are in.  This code as is will exit your `value()` method as soon as it goes through the first iteration.

I think if you are looking to print something you would want `System.out.println(word);`

This will print your word for each letter in the word.

Answer (score 0):

By invoking `run.value()`, you essentially did nothing. Based on your implementation of `value()`, the method will terminate on the first iteration of the while loop.

Since you are printing the `toString()` of `Box`, maybe what you wanted to do is to override the `toString` method in the following way:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(word).append("\n");
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to call value two times since you call it the toString, the value method will return only once, the return needs to be outside the for loop, and since there is a constructor setting word to null there is a NPE risk in the value method, this should do it :

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Box{
  private String word;

  public Box(){ word = null; }

  public Box(String s){ this.word = s; }

  public void setWord(String s){ this.word = s; }

  public String value(){
    //beware of the NPE
    if(word==null)
      return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < word.length() ; i++){
      sb.append(word).append("\n");
    }

    return sb.toString();
  }

  public String toString(){ return this.value(); }

}

public class BoxRunner{

  public static void main ( String[] args ){
    Box run = new Box();
    run.setWord("hippo");

    System.out.print(run.toString());
  }
}
```

But if you don't need the value method outside of the class then consider putting the code of value in the toString directly instead of calling value from inside toString

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know what is meant by `return`. When a method returns, it terminates. So in your `value` method, it terminates on the first iteration of the loop.

So you should not return a value in your `value` method. Change that to `void`. I think essentially what you are doing here is copying `word` for x times. A better name of the method would be `copyMyself`. Now let's see how to implement the method:

```
public void copyMyself () {
    int length = word.length();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        builder.append (word);
    }
    word = builder.toString ();
}
```

Now let me explain this. First you put the length of the word in a variable. Then you create a `StringBuilder`. A `StringBuilder` allows you to do all kinds of things with strings. In this case, I used the `append` method of it, which inserts the parameter at the end of the string. This way, the `word` repeats itself for `word.length()` times. And finally you set `word` to the string builder because then you can use `toString()` to get the `word`.

The above would print

```
hippohippohippohippohippo
```

If you want to have 5 *lines* of hippos, change the loop to this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
    builder.append (word);
    builder.append ("\r\n");
}
```